# How to refer to current iteration of hash loop in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a hash like so

```
net:ip { '':
ip => {
    ip1 => {
       addr => '192.168.10.1',
       device => 'eth0',
    },
    ip2 => {
      addr => '192.168.50.10',
      device => 'eth10',
    },
}
}
```

In my manifest I call like so

```
define net::ip (
$ip={},
) {
  ...
}
```

my question is how do I refer to the current loop of the hash iteration. I want to be able to use the "dev" field in this manifest, but since the hash has ip1,ip2 I can't tell what number its on?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: You're passing that hash to the defined type, but you're not showing us what's happening in that defined type; you'll need to clarify how exactly you're 'looping' over the hash - is it within an erb template?

Comment: Apologies, thought that part wasn't relevant. Currently I am iterating over the loop in my erb template. But I need to access the device for each hash element inside the manifest. So really that's where my problem is. I understand that we can't do loops in manifests, but is there a way to get the device from a call? Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

Following example may help. Create the hash separately and access it through a define type.

```
  $foo = [{"addr" => "bar", "port" => "1"},                                     
          {"addr" => "bat", "port" => "2"}]                                     
  testmod::bar {$foo:}                                                          
  define testmod::bar () {                                                      
    $var1 = $name["addr"]                                                       
    $var2 = $name["port"]                                                       
    notify {"${var1}_${var2}": }                                                
  }
```